# R: How to delete an account from shinyapps.io?

Tags: shiny, rstudio, shiny-server, shinyapps

I have an account on [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/), which I used for shiny web app deployment. However, I do not use it anymore and I want to delete this account. Is there any option, how to do it? I can't find any option like that in account settings.

Comment: It is part of RStudio, maybe contact the support? https://community.rstudio.com/tags/shinyappsio

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/delete-account-shinyapps-io/22692